# Mensaje de subproceso anulado

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Soy muy nuevo en Visual Basic.NET y tengo el siguiente problema. Quiero hacer un login con Sql Server pero cuando ingreso los datos y le doy aceptar me sale un mensaje:

> "subproceso anulado"

Y tengo que dar aceptar para que recién funcione. Como lo podría solucionarlo?

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Diseño
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim cn As String = "DATA SOURCE=RENZO\SQLEXPRESS;INITIAL CATALOG=INFORMATICA2050;INTEGRATED SECURITY=TRUE"
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim comando As String = "select * from alumno where nombres = '" & txtUsuario.Text & "' and apellidos = '" & txtContraseña.Text & "'"
    Try
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(comando, cn)
        da.Fill(dt)
        If dt.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
            Response.Redirect("NUEVOF.aspx")
        Else
            MsgBox("usuario o contraseña incorrecta")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: es vb.net o asp.net? la linea que te tira el error es el msgbox?

Comment: es asp.net , el error me sale en un msgbox, cuando le doy aceptar recien me manda a la pagina que quiero abrir

Comment: es que no se puede usar un msgbox en asp.net.. pq es un proceso que se ejecuta sobre el servidor... necesitar un control msgbox de usuario o usar javascript...

Comment: es mensaje que me sale es del try Catch , si lo quito me corre normal, pero no se si sera recomendable quitarle

Comment: igual nunca se va a mostrar el msgbox...

Comment: `MsgBox` es para entornos `Desktop` , para web como es `ASP` será mejor buscar opciones _librerias_  desde el lado cliente. _Javascript_

Answer (score 0):

El error de subproceso anulado se da porque no esta permitido en ASP.NET usar un msgbox. vas a tener que buscar otro método para mostrar el error.

Podrias utilizar un control de usuario que muestre un formulario modal al volver, o un javascript que verifique la validez de los datos.

Comment: entonces como podría mostrar el mensaje de error del cath?

Answer (score 0):

Vamos por partes:

1. Como te han comentado, el `Msgbox` es para entornos de escritorio. Lo suyo es que lo que vaya al `catch` lo almacenes en un fichero de log o tabla de base de datos (como prefieras) ya que por un lado, a ti como desarrollador te interesa poder consultar los errores que han ocurrido para arreglarlos si es necesario (puede ser un corte de conexión y ahi no tienes nada que hacer) y por otro lado no es correcto mostrar al usuario el mensaje de excepción porque puede contener información sensible y sin embargo le muestres un mensaje controlado.
2. En este caso concreto, la excepción que te está dando será seguramente el intento de mostrar el `Msgbox` de login incorrecto, por lo que de nuevo, lo más correcto es que

   - muestres un mensaje controlado en un label destinado a ello,
   - hagas el login mediante una llamada `ajax` para mostrar un `alert` con `javascript` o
   - simplemente redirijas a una página de error genérica tuya.

Te dejo a continuación una pequeña modificación de tu código, comentando las lineas que cambio:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Diseño
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim cn As String = "DATA SOURCE=RENZO\SQLEXPRESS;INITIAL CATALOG=INFORMATICA2050;INTEGRATED SECURITY=TRUE"
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim comando As String = "select * from alumno where nombres = '" & txtUsuario.Text & "' and apellidos = '" & txtContraseña.Text & "'"
        Try
            da = New SqlDataAdapter(comando, cn)
            da.Fill(dt)
            If dt.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
                Response.Redirect("NUEVOF.aspx")
            Else
                'Cambiamos el Msgbox por un mensaje controlado en un label creado en la página para esto
                this.lblLoginError.Text = "Usuario o contraseña incorrecta"
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Volcamos el valor de la excepción en un fichero
            ClaseGestoraErrores.EscribirEnFichero(ex.Message)
            'Cambiamos el Msgbox por un mensaje controlado en un label creado en la página para esto
            this.lblMensajesError.Text = "Se ha producido un error en la aplicación"
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

Por último te recomiendo que modifiques tus consultas para utilizar prepared statements (por ejemplo), ya que tal y como lo tienes ahora, tu aplicación es vulnerable a inyecciones SQL.